# How to keep Swift Socket IO running when app enters background?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am working on an application that needs to keep a socket connection alive if the app going into the background. While the app is in foreground the socket connection runs fine but when it enters background it closes. I have tried using `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` but it is still closing the connection. My `Info.plist` has the necessary background values set already.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it with ios (dual to apple policy https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

You should do it by implement remote notification for IOS.